# SwiftUI - List Line Separator Inset like iOS Settings App

Tags: ios, list, swiftui, line, separator

I'm trying to achieve the behavior that's also seen in in the iOS Settings App or for instance the Roborock App (see screenshots below). I'd like to go for an Icon and then give an inset to the line separator.

[image]
[image]

I already tried:

```
UITableView.appearance().separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 80)
```

but this doesn't work with SwiftUI 3.0 / iOS 15.1

Here's the full code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Test")
            }) {
                SettingsCell2(title: "Test", iconName: "bell.badge.fill")
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Test")
            }) {
                SettingsCell2(title: "Test", iconName: "bell.badge.fill")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsCell2: View {
    
    var title : String
    var iconName : String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            
            ZStack {

                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous)
                    .fill(Color.red)
                
                Image(systemName: iconName)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)

            }
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30, alignment: .center)

            Text(title)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)

        }

    }
}

struct ListTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListTest()
    }
}
```

Any Ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: did you give the answer a try?

Comment: Is there a new solution to this problem？

Answer (score 1):

## iOS 16

**With iOS 16 the behavior of these row dividers changed to the way you are looking for.**
So by default the separator will inset to align with the `Text()` as long as you are using the default `.insetGrouped` list style.

If you want to customize them anyway you can use the `listRowSeparatorLeading` and `listRowSeparatorTrailing` alignment guides (new with iOS 16). For more information check out [this article](https://sarunw.com/posts/swiftui-list-row-separator-insets/).

Answer (score 0):

#### Xcode 14 / iOS 16

Actually all is need is `.listStyle(.insetGrouped)`

[image]

More details is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73013223/12299030)

Comment: The OP is asking about iOS 16 so this answer is not helpful.

Answer (score -3):

add `.listStyle(.sidebar)` to your list

```swift
struct ListTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button(action: {
                print("Test")
            }) {
                SettingsCell2(title: "Test", iconName: "bell.badge.fill")
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Test")
            }) {
                SettingsCell2(title: "Test", iconName: "bell.badge.fill")
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.sidebar)
    }
}
```

To make the row looks better, you should use `Label` instead of `Image` and `Text`